# fwrite or file_get_contents not copying full file

Tags: php, utf-8, file-get-contents, fwrite

The file in the file path contains no JavaScript; it's just plain HTML or PHP scripts. They are also local. I'm trying to convert any file in the main path to UTF-8 before it is stored as a link in a menu. I have no control of the files that are uploaded except that they are either PHP or HTML.

An example is that the file size of one file is changed from 6,808 to 572 with the following:

```
$filesize = filesize($filepath);
$filecontent = file_get_contents($filepath,FALSE,NULL,0,$filesize); 
$utf8content = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($filecontent, mb_detect_order(),
                     true), "UTF-8", $filecontent); 

$fp = fopen($filepath, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $utf8content);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: How about `file_put_contents`? you could actually replace all the code in your question with this simple native PHP function, obviously, except for the part of `$filecontent`

Comment: Is the contents still the same after saving the file . and what is max executing time in your server .

Comment: Will  file_put_contents save in utf-8?

Comment: same error occurs even if I use file_put_contents.... 
the content is the same, but shortened. I'm at a loss here.